# Add topnavigation bar to Infopath form

Tags: list, infopath

I add new elements to a list with form created with Infopath.
Unfortunately, the Topnavigation bar is missing. Is there a way I could add it
to my form page (newifs.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

It's the OOTB function to deploy the form like that, what you could do would be to create a blank page, edit the page and insert a InfoPath Form Web part and add your form there.

Then you can change the default list-form for the list to point to new page from the SharePoint Designer.

Comment: I've tried that. But only the ribbon with commands shows up.

Comment: What navigation bar is missing?

Comment: It's missing the one with the links, site logo, and search box, on the top.

Comment: Use F12 developer tool to see if the element is being overridden by something.

Comment: I see the content is there in the Html but it doesn't show up

Comment: Does the form open as a new page or as a modal dialog? Is "IsDlg=1" presented in the back of the URL when the form is open?

Comment: The form opens in the same browser window of its site. It's not a modal dialog.  In the url there is not IsDlg=1

Comment: I think it's the OOTB function to deploy the form like that, what you could do would be to create a blank page, edit the page and insert a InfoPath Form Web part and add your form there. Then you can change the default listform for the list to point to new page from SharePoint Designer.

Comment: Thanks, it works.if you put it as an answer I'll flag .it

Comment: Glad to hear! :)